# Batch file Programming Help required

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file program that gets a username and password from the user and checks them by comparing them with two files, `username.dat` and `password.dat`.

The username is stored in `%username%` and password in `%password%`. What I'd like to know is, how do I check these variables against the files username.dat and password.dat?

I've tried using this:

```
echo %username% >U.dat
echo %Password% >P.dat
COMP U.dat Username.dat
```

But what value to check? I mean in C or C++ we can check for a return value, but what about this `COMP`?

Comment: Please use more informative titles in the future...

Comment: why do you want to store passwords in a plain file? why do you want a single user and password? why don't you rely on other well proven methods?

Answer (score 2):

Storing a username and password in files seems like a bad idea to me. But assuming you are going to do it any way...

There is no need to echo your variables to temporary files prior to doing a comparison. There are multiple ways to do your comparison more directly. Here is one method. I'm using delayed expansion so that it supports special characters like `&` `|` etc in the password (or username).

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set userPassOK=1
findstr /x /c:"!username!" Username.dat || set "userPassOK="
findstr /x /c:"!password!" Password.dat || set "userPassOK="
if defined userPassOK (echo username and password passed) else echo Invalid username/password
```